# Which is the better way to test our enhanced tasks and custom plugins in Gradle?

Tags: plugins, gradle, task, spock

From Gradle's [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#N16666) we can see that we can test our custom plugin using **org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder**, but in [Gradle's code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/351e5d7988d451bf551410b8e59797c98c3152ff/subprojects/ivy/src/test/groovy/org/gradle/api/publish/ivy/tasks/PublishToIvyRepositoryTest.groovy) often is used **Spock Framework**.

Which is the better way. Or when to use Spock and when ProjectBuilder? Why Spock is preferred? Does it give more power than ProjectBuilder in terms of testing Tasks or Plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Spock or JUnit, not Spock or `ProjectBuilder`. Whether you use Spock or JUnit (or any other testing framework) is entirely up to you. Note that `ProjectBuilder` is only good for *unit* testing tasks and plugins. For integration testing (i.e. where builds are not just configured but also executed), you should use the tooling API.

PS: There are plans to provide more support for testing Gradle tasks and plugins in the future, but for now, the tools of choice are `ProjectBuilder` and the tooling API.

Comment: I am still confused. Spock can be use for integration tests and unit tests, but ProjectBuilder only for unit tests? So for unit testing I decide which to use? Spock is external framework(written by you), ProjectBuilder is internal class provided by Gradle?

Comment: They are entirely different things. Spock is a general-purpose testing framework roughly comparable to JUnit or TestNG. `ProjectBuilder` is a (testing framework agnostic) utility class for unit testing Gradle tasks and plugins, and it is part of Gradle's public API. The Gradle codebase also has lots of other test infrastructure (JUnit rules, JUnit and Spock base classes, etc.), but that's only for internal use. (Some of this infrastructure may be exposed as a public API in the future.)